# displaying nested json in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I seem to be having difficulty in grasping how to drill down to get to nested  JSON and display it on a page using angular. For example I have the following JSON structure and I want to display the connectivity products under portfolio in an ng-repeat...

```
{
"addons": [
    ...
],

"attributes": [     
    ...
],
"portfolios": [
    {
        "connectivity": [
            {
                "product-1": {
                    "label": "product-1",
                    "description": "Description in here"
                }
            },
            {
                "product-2": {
                    "label": "product-2",
                    "description": "Description in here"
                }
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

}

So far I have tried it two different ways.

```
$scope.listOfProducts = allProducts.data.portfolios.connectivity;
```

and in the ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat='product in listOfProducts.portfolios.connectivity'
```

What would be the correct way to loop through and display the 'connectivity' products in a ng-repeat? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've changed the JSON to this structure...

```
{
"addons": [
...
],

"attributes": [     
    ...
],
"portfolios": [
{
    "connectivity": [
        {
                "label": "product-1",
                "description": "Description in here"
        },
        {
                "label": "product-2",
                "description": "Description in here"
        }
    ]

}
]
```

But I still can't seem to get ng-repeat to display the products in connectivity.

$scope.listOfProducts = allProducts.data.portfolios.connectivity

Comment: Shouldn't you write `ng-repeat='product in listOfProducts` directly!

Comment: Isn't it listOfProducts.portfolios[0].connectivity ?

Comment: Jeremy - thanks. that seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `listOfProducts` is already set to the `connectivity` array, you would just `ng-repeat="product in listOfProducts"`

```
<div ng-repeat="product in listOfProducts">
  {{product.label}}
</div>
```

**Edit:** Well, your array is sort of irregular, since you're creating a property called `product-[index]` for each item.  Do you have control of the data which is returned?  Your array should just have the objects, like:

```
"connectivity": [
    {
        "label": "product-1",
        "description": "Description in here"
    },
    {
        "label": "product-2",
        "description": "Description in here"
    }
]
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. I think we can change the json like you suggested